# $(0,\infty)$ not compact as a subset of the normed vector space $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$?

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces

Assume I want to show that $(0,\infty)\subset(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ is not compact.

I went on to use the sequence $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $(0,\infty)$ which doesn't converge in $(0,\infty)$, because its limit is $0$.

Edit: I use the following definition of a compact set: If $V$ is a normed vector space, then $A\subset V$ is compact, if every sequence in $A$ has a convergent subsequence in $A$.

So now all is left to show that $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has NO convergent subsequence. That's where I am stuck. I cannot use propositions one learns in Analysis 1 (e.g.) because $\mathbb{R}$ is only a normed vector space and no field!

Could anyone start me off?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have to specify where convergence takes place. The definition should be "every sequence in $A$ has a convergent subsequence *in $A$*".

Comment: Thank you for the remark. I edited it.

Comment: What would a sequence of natural numbers that converges in $\mathbb{R}$ look like?

Comment: Now, say you have a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $A$ and a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ that converges to $x\in A$ in $A$. Do you agree that $(x_{n_k})_k$ also converges to $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. If so, can you convince yourself that no subsequence of $(1/n)_n$ has a limit in $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Thank you! This is really straight forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $(1/n)$ converges to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, all its subsequences converge to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, it has *no* subsequence that has a limit in $(0,+\infty)$.

This works, but to be honest, the most direct way to justify that $(0,+\infty)$ is not compact is to say that it is not bounded.

Comment: Or that it is not closed (as $1/n \rightarrow 0$ outside $(0,\infty)$).

Comment: Yes, but basically the "non-closedness" is the first argument. I agree that it is straightforward for everyone who knows a little bit of topology, but for a beginner, the non-boundedness is (in my opinion) the easiest thing to see.

Comment: Thank you. It's clear to me now. And yes, you are right - it's just that (in my materials) I couldn't find this kind of definition for compact. I know that compact means bounded and closed - but i know this only for $\mathbb{R}$ as a field so I wasn't sure if I could use this.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Fair point.

Comment: @manuel459 Actually, "compact means bounded and closed" is not always true. What you have to remember is that "compact implies bounded and closed" is always true (in any metric space), and that "compact means bounded and closed" is true in finite-dimensional normed vector space (of course, $\mathbb{R}$ is finite-dimensional vector space).

Comment: This is Riesz proposition right? (I am just trying to arrange my thoughts). Namely:
A bounded and closed subset of a normed vector space is compact if and only if the normed vector space is finite-dimensional.

Comment: @manuel459 Which Riesz theorem ? The one stating that a normed vector space has finite dimension if and only if its closed unit ball is compact ?

Comment: Yes exactly - because i found this (helpful) proposition in my materials although its spelled wrong which made me not realize it.

Comment: @manuel459 Well, actually, the fact that if the dimension is finite, then the closed unit ball is compact is the easy part of Riesz theorem (you can try to prove it, it is a good exercice !). This theorem is rather useful for its reciprocal, ie for the part saying that if the dimension is infinite, then the closed unit ball *is not* compact (which is more difficult to prove)

Comment: i understand. but I can still use it this way though don't I? Just to make sure - which version is correct:  A bounded and closed subset of a normed vector space is compact if and only if the normed vector space is finite-dimensional. OR  A bounded and closed subset of a normed vector space is compact if and only if this subset is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Neither is correct, actually : even in infinite dimension, you can always find bounded and closed subsets that *are* compact (take just a singleton !). This is the equivalence (compact $\Leftrightarrow$ closed/bounded) which is true if and only if the dimension is finite (again, the implication $\Rightarrow$ is always true, this is the reverse way which is interesting). And finally, you consider here subsets that are not always sub-vector spaces, so what is important is the dimension of the "big" vectior space you are in.

Comment: I get it now. So correct is: Let V be a normed vector space that is finite-dimensional: Then a subset A is compact if and only if A is bounded and closed. Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: This version is absolutely correct, you get it :)